# html listbox click event(html helper class)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am using asp .net mvc 4.0 ,vs2010

I have a listbox and textarea:

```
<div class="editor-list-field">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TableColumn, new SelectList(Model.TableColumn), new { @class = "listofcolumn" , name="listofcolumn"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TableColumn)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-multiline-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { cols=60,@rows=10, @class = "textarea" name = "textarea"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
```

I am wondering, how can i generate an event like `listbox_doubleclick`(just for example: it could be like anything) and do what i have to.

I have to show the selected items from listbox to textarea for. And i want to do it simply.

I am surfing the net for a solution since yesterday, but could not apply anything to have the job done.

**EDIT:**

Some jQuery I have tried  but no result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
$(function() {
    ​$('#listofcolumn')​.dblclick(function() { alert('clicked');
        if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
            var selectedId = $(this).val();
            var selectedText = $(this).text();
            alert(selectedText);
            $('#textarea').val(selectedText);
        }


      });
 });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery and [dblClick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

```
$('textarea').on('dblclick', function () {
  alert('hola');
});
```